# Intoduction to Visual Basic (vb)

Tags: vb.net

We have an integer number and we have need to factorise this x number then write and sum up odd and even numbers of x.

How can I write this in Visual Basic ?

Comment: learning VB can be fun. However, what have you read/done to start on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To x - 1

If x Mod i = 0 Then
Print i
End If

Next
```

for example gives you the factors of x (which is given as you said). If it's an exam question, you really should read some tutorials or book chapters about VB, because it's a very basic problem you asked for. I never wrote a line of VB before and still could answer a part of your question just by using google and some basic introductions. And I'm not going to write an exam in VB ;-)

edit: OK here is the final solution

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim sumEven As Integer
Dim sumOdd As Integer

For i = 1 To x - 1

  If x Mod i = 0 Then

    If x Mod 2 = 0 Then
      sumEven = sumEven + i
    Else
      sumOdd = sumOdd + i
    End If    

  End If

Next
```

sumEven is the sum of even numbers, etc.

Comment: you are right, but after that we have to sum this i numbers even or odd; teacher want to output like this "total even numbers=" and "total odd numbers=" how can i do it ?

Comment: create variables `totalEven` and `totalOdd` and do `totalEven = totalEven + 1` and `totalOdd = totalOdd + 1`

Comment: I posted the final solution to my original answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

x mod 2 will give 1 when the number is odd and 0 when the number is even where x is your number.

Also,

From http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet3655.htm

this finds if a number is a factor

Hope you find this helpful and experiment.

```
Dim N, x As Integer

Cls

N = InputBox("Enter Number")
For x = 1 To N - 1

If N Mod x = 0 Then
Print x
End If

Next
Print N
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim n As Integer

Do
n = InputBox("Enter Value of n") 
if n mod(2)=0 
then
msgbox("your number is even") 
else 
msgbox("your number is odd")
End If

Next

Dim i As Integer
Dim sum As Integer
sum=0
For i = 1 To n 

if x Mod (i) = 0 
then
sum=sum+i
End If

msgbox("Total factorising number of n is "+i)
```